# My timer script for minecraft is not working

Tags: lua, timer, minecraft

I have a problem with my Minecraft timer script I tried to add a function that saves the time values from worlds in a document. The timer worked completely fine before i added this function...
Code:

```
name = "Timer"
description = "Just a normal Timer."
positionX = 0
positionY = 0
sizeX = 24
sizeY = 10
scale = 1

START_STOP_KEY = 0x55 --or 'U'
RESET_KEY = 0x4A --or 'J'
 --
--[[
    

    if you wish to change the key you can take the key code from here
    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes
]] -------------script-code-------------
previoustime = 0
state = 0
startTime = 0
stopTime = 0

ImportedLib = importLib("readfile.lua")


function keyboard(key, isDown)
    if (isDown == true) then
        if (key == RESET_KEY) then
            state = 0
        elseif (key == START_STOP_KEY) then
            if (state == 0) then
                state = 1
                startTime = os.time()
            elseif (state == 1) then
                state = 2
                previoustime = os.time()
                stopTime = os.time()
            elseif (state == 2) then
                state = 1
                startTime = startTime + os.time() - stopTime
            end
        end
    end
end

TimerText = "00:00"
TextColor = {r = 30, g = 255, b = 30, a = 255}
function doubleDigit(number)
    if (number < 10) then
        return "0" .. math.floor(number)
    else
        return math.floor(number)
    end
end

function timeText(time)
    local result = ""
    local days = 0
    while (time > 86399) do
        days = days + 1
        time = time - 86400
    end

    local hours = 0
    while (time > 3599) do
        hours = hours + 1
        time = time - 86400
    end

    local minutes = 0
    while (time > 59) do
        minutes = minutes + 1
        time = time - 60
    end

    if (days == 0) then
        if (hours == 0) then
            return doubleDigit(minutes) .. ":" .. doubleDigit(time)
        else
            return math.floor(hours) .. " : " .. doubleDigit(minutes) .. ":" .. doubleDigit(time)
        end
    else
        return math.floor(days) ..
            " : " .. doubleDigit(hours) .. " : " .. doubleDigit(minutes) .. ":" .. doubleDigit(time)
    end
end

function update()
    if (state == 0) then
        TextColor = {r = 255, g = 0, b = 0, a = 255}
        TimerText = "00:00"
    elseif (state == 1) then
        TimerText = timeText(os.time() - startTime)
        TextColor = {r = 0, g = 255, b = 255, a = 255}
    elseif (state == 2) then
        TimerText = timeText(stopTime - startTime)
        TextColor = {r = 255, g = 255, b = 0, a = 255}
    end
end

function render()
    local font = gui.font()
    local tw = font.width(TimerText)

    gfx.color(0, 0, 0, 0)
    gfx.rect(0, 0, tw + 4, 10)

    gfx.color(TextColor.r, TextColor.g, TextColor.b, TextColor.a)
    gfx.text(2, 1, TimerText)
end
```

This is the function i want to add

```
if (state == 1) then
      local worldName = server.worldName()
      io.open(local worldName".txt", "w")
      io.output(file)
      io.write(time)
      io.close(file)
  end

if (state == 0) then
      local worldName = server.worldName()
      io.open(local worldName".txt", "r")
      io.output(file)
      time = (file:read())
      io.close(file)
  end
```

Comment: Replace `io.open(local worldName".txt", "r")` with `io.open(worldName..".txt", "r")`.  And read "Programming in Lua" book.

Comment: It says attempt to access a nil value (global 'file') @EgorSkriptunoff

Comment: It means file not found.

Comment: How can i fix that?

Comment: Obviously, you should create the file.  Lua can not read the file that is absent.

Comment: but the file gets named by the world its custom

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to concatenate (join) two strings `io.open(local worldName".txt", "r")`. You should use the concat operator (double dot) for that:

```
local s1 = "Hello "
local s2 = "World!!!"
local s3 = s1..s2
print(s3)
```

This program will print the string "Hello world!!" (without the quotes).

Also, the you are only supposed to use the local keyword when declaring a variable.
So:

```
if (state == 1) then
      local worldName = server.worldName()
      io.open(worldName..".txt", "w")
      io.output(file)
      io.write(time)
      io.close(file)
  end

if (state == 0) then
      local worldName = server.worldName()
      io.open(worldName..".txt", "r")
      io.output(file)
      time = (file:read())
      io.close(file)
  end
```

This code is the correct version of what you wanted to write. I removed the incorrect uses of the local keyword and added the concat operator.